# Intermittent Authentication failed or partial success error

Tags: chilkat, chilkat-sshkey, chilkat-ftp

I am getting an intermittent `Authentication failed or partial success. (1)` error.

```
ChilkatLog:
  AuthenticatePw:
    DllDate: May 25 2017
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.68
    UnlockPrefix: XXXXXXXXX
    Architecture: Little Endian; 64-bit
    Language: .NET 4.5 / x64
    VerboseLogging: 0
    login: XXXXXXX
    sshAuthenticatePw:
      requestUserAuthService:
        sendServiceRequest:
          svcName: ssh-userauth
          SentServiceReq: ssh-userauth
        --sendServiceRequest
        ssh-userauth service accepted.
      --requestUserAuthService
      AuthMethods: password
      passwordAuth:
        Sent login/password
        Authentication failed or partial success. (1)
        PartialSuccess1: 0
        AuthList: password
        important:
          This is likely a simple invalid login and/or password error,
          meaning your application did not send the correct login and/or password.
        --important
      --passwordAuth
    --sshAuthenticatePw
    Failed.
  --AuthenticatePw
--ChilkatLog
```

What does the `(1)` in `Authentication failed or partial success. (1)` mean? Is it the `AuthFailReason` mentioned [here](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/xChilkatSFtpRef.html#:%7E:text=top-,AuthFailReason,-AuthFailReason%20As%20Long)

Answer (score 0):

The LastErrorText is designed to provide information for quick resolution of problems.  It contains the information that would likely be needed by the developer to understand the cause of a problem.  In our opinion, it is  much better than an obscure single-line message or an error code.

It also provides information for Chilkat -- so that if you send us the LastErrorText, we can see context and usually understand the cause of the problem and the solution in one step.  Some lines in the LastErrorText might be obscure to the application developer.  That's OK, because they are lines meant for us.

In this case the "Authentication failed or partial success. (1)" line is telling Chilkat the execution path that was taken in the internal code.  We don't have to guess.

The SSH authentication protocol is such that it's possible for the server to respond with an SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE response, but indicate partial success.  In this case, the partial success was 0 (false), so it points to a hard failure -- most likely the simple case that the username and/or password was incorrect.

There is one more possibility, which is somewhat rare. If the server also accepts keyboard-interactive, then you can set Ssh.UncommonOptions = "KeyboardInteractiveFollowup" (or SFtp.UncommonOptions = "KeyboardInteractiveFollowup") to cause Chilkat to retry with a keyboard-interactive request.

Comment: PS> The suggestion for UncommonOptions = "KeyboardInteractiveFollowup"  would require updating to the latest version of Chilkat.  I don't think that option existed in v9.5.0.68